# Nunjucks string embed at render rather than compile time

Tags: nunjucks

We have a template that's taking up to 40 seconds to render which has been attributed to a JavaScript inline insertion being performed at what appears to be compile and not render time. We found this by turning cache on.

The workflow 'dump' is about 2Mb.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var form = document.getElementById('workflow');
    window.app.caseSection(form, '{{ workflow | dump }}');
  });
</script>
```

One option is to abort the approach entirely and load the data later via ajax. Is there another way to solve it inline?

Comment: Are you use [precompiling](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#precompiling)? It also reduces `nunjucks`-library.

Comment: No, nothing other than res.render(). Switching on cache resolves the issue but doesn't make that much sense where as I expect the 'workflow' variable to be inserted at render not compile, however this isn't the case.